# INSERT with IF Exists in SQL, SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

how to check the value exist before insert?

```
INSERT INTO DeliveryOrder (ContactName, ContactID) VALUES ('Andy', (SELECT ContactID FROM Contact WHERE ContactName = 'Andy'))
```

I want to verify whether the ContactID is exist before insert the record.

Had try below but not working:

```
INSERT INTO DeliveryOrder (ContactName, ContactID) VALUES ('Andy', (SELECT ContactID FROM Contact WHERE ContactName = 'Andy')) WHERE IF Exists (SELECT ContactID FROM Contact WHERE ContactName = 'Andy')
```

Comment: You could check before hand (in a transaction), or you might find `INSERT OR REPLACE` or `INSERT OR IGNORE` to be useful (see [SQLite docs](http://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)).

Comment: Do not check for existence. Define a unique constrain and ignore constrain violation errors during import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO DeliveryOrder (ContactName, ContactID)
 select 'Andy', ContactID
   from Contact
  WHERE ContactName = 'Andy'
```

Comment: this woks better - it helps to think of your insert as recording your select - so if you write the select statement to return the values you need first then the Insert statement appears above it (with difficulties around sub queries)

Comment: but my contactname will be another fix value, then contactID will be take from a table.

Comment: @user14351 You can specify any values that are not in the table in the clause"select". Example updated.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT ContactID
        FROM Contact  c
        WHERE
            c.ContactName ='Andy'
        )
Insert Into DeliveryOrder (ContactName, ContactID)
        VALUES ('Andy', (SELECT top 1 ContactID FROM Contact WHERE ContactName = 'Andy'))
```

Try this